# Example of Google's Geocoding API is not working

Tags: java, eclipse, google-maps

I wanted to test the GeocodingAPI-example of the googles hompage [(the code)](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java).

I'm working with Java in eclipse and I already added the library "google-maps-services 0.1.7" to my project. This is my code:

```
package test;

import com.google.maps.*;
import com.google.maps.model.GeocodingResult;

public class Distance {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext().setApiKey("AIza...");
    GeocodingResult[] results =  GeocodingApi.geocode(context,
        "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View, CA 94043").await();
    System.out.println(results[0].formattedAddress);    
    }
}
```

When I want to run the code, the following problem is shown in the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient
at com.google.maps.GeoApiContext.<init>(GeoApiContext.java:50)
at test.Distance.main(Distance.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 2 more
```

I changed the API to my personal API. What is wrong in this code? Are there mistakes in the import-instructions?

Comment: The log says you dont have the `OkHttpClient` class, you probably didnt import the `OkHttp` correctly to your project. For Eclipse, you can download the latest jar file or grad it via Maven, see instruction here: https://github.com/square/okhttp